# How to add new service/app for agent in esxi host?

Tags: esxi

I made a sample service application as to esxi host.
copy start-script for service to /etc/init.d/
copy app for specific directory. /opt/app/sample_agent

However, they are removed automatically after rebooting esxi host.

I think there is a functionality on ESXi to do.

I want to persist them always.  How to reovle that issue?

I do test but they disapper.